# Mathematical operation on angular template

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

Whenever I a try something like this in view template it is working as expected.

`{{20*30}}`

but whenever I  try

`{{somevalue1*somevalue2}}`

Where `somevalue1` and `somevalue2` both are coming from component and `somevalue2` is coming from api and it is inside an array, it is displaying NaN.

How to deal with that?

Is it because of the String value?

How to convert that in Number in template?

Comment: Please, share more code.  Specifically, javascript code to get a better view of how you're getting data.  Further, share the types of those variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it because of the String value?

Yes, it is. You can't easily access the windows scope in template scope, so I would make a method:

```
calculateStuff(){
  return Number(somevalue1) * Number(somevalue2);
}
```

And in template:

```
{{calculateStuff()}}
```

If the string doesn't start with characters representing number, it will still return NaN.

Comment: Actually i am getting response like this 3,947.5825 where it is comma separated so whenever i am converting this to number comma is getting inside that and returning NAN again. Any idea to deal with that?

Comment: Look at vojtechs answer down below. He is correct in everything. The number is internationalized. Just replace the commas with empty string and then call Number method as previously suggested.

Answer (score 1):

`somevalue1` `somevalue2` are probably strings. You'll need to share more code to get a real answer, though.

Add `{{somevalue1}}` and `{{somevalue2}}` to the template as well, just so you can be sure the template is receiving the values you expect.

Comment: My response is like this 3,947.5825 where it is comma separated so whenever i am converting this to number comma is getting inside that and returning NAN again. Any idea to deal with that?

Comment: Oh, yea you're gonna have to remove the commas. There are other questions about that on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the string value that is formatted according to some locale ( in your case it is [US locale](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html) )

You can eighter:

- convert the strings to values on data retrieving
- create angular transform pipe
- use a helper function/method in your template
- if you are able, adjust data on the server side (it is a good practice sending raw data and formatting them when needed)

There are several ways how to handle the conversion. If this is the only format you receive that numbers. Simply replace the comma `Number('1,234.42'.replace(',', ''))` or use some of the libs that were created for this purpose like [NumeralJS](http://numeraljs.com/)